# Dynamic binding with User Control does not work as Static is working in Silverlight and MVVM

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, silverlight-4.0, user-controls, prism-4

I have created sample User Control

**RestrictedBox.xaml**

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Converters:EnumToVisibilityConverter x:Key="enumToVisConverter" />
        <Converters:EnumToVisibilityConverterReverse x:Key="enumToVisConverterReverse" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="Auto">
        <StackPanel Margin="0">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" Visibility="{Binding Type,Converter={StaticResource enumToVisConverter}}" BorderBrush="Green" />
            <PasswordBox Password="{Binding Value}" Visibility="{Binding Type,Converter={StaticResource enumToVisConverterReverse}}" BorderBrush="Red" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**RestrictedBox.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class RestrictedBox : UserControl
    {
        public RestrictedBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //If i bind static value and uncomment following line then it is working.
            //If i bind static value and comment following line then it is not working
            this.DataContext = this;
            //Dynamic binding does not work using this code.  
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(RestrictedBox), new PropertyMetadata("", ValueChanged));
        private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public Mode Type
        {
            get { return (Mode)GetValue(TypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TypeProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Type", typeof(Mode), typeof(RestrictedBox), new PropertyMetadata(TypeChanged));
        private static void TypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

**LoginViewModel.cs**

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IRegionMemberLifetime
{
        private string _UserName = "Imdadhusen Sunasara";
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return _UserName; }
            set
            {
                _UserName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }
}
```

**LoginView.xaml** (*This following line does not work with binding*)

```
<control:RestrictedBox Value="{Binding UserName}" Type="Text" />
```

**This is working** (*with static binding*)

```
<control:RestrictedBox Value="Imdadhusen" Type="Text" />
```

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Comment: First of all, I see you have a lot of problems with understanding what binding is. For example, there is no such thing like "static binding". Binding can be only "dynamic". I can hardly recommend book "Pro Silverlight 4 in C#" from Mattew McDonald - read it one time and you will save huge amount of your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually It should work. Can you please verify that the DataContext of parent container of below control doesn't refering to any other property of viewmodel.

```
<control:RestrictedBox Value="Imdadhusen" Type="Text" />
```

eg. Something like below.

```
<StackPanel DataContext={Binding CurrentUser}>

<control:RestrictedBox Value="{Binding UserName}"

 Type="Text" />

</StackPanel>
```

May be this help you....

Answer (score 2):

I have got solution from following

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/250206.aspx/1?Dynamic+binding+with+User+Control+does+not+work+as+Static+is+working+in+Silverlight+and+MVVM

Thanks everybody who trying to help me.
Imdadhusen